# Optimal way to generate download urls

Tags: firebase-storage

I am creating a spaced repetition flashcard app using react-native. Each flashcard includes an audio file that I am storing in firebase storage. There are roughly 10000 audio files that I have stored in Firebase storage but they all have a similar naming structure (ie flashcard1.mp3, flashcard2.mp3,...). Each time the user logs into the app, they will have around 50 cards to review and 20 new cards to look at. Currently, I am gathering the download URLs for each of the 70 flashcards, inside a for loop, with the following code:

```
const audiourl = await storage()
            .ref('path/flashcard'+cardIndex+'.mp3')
            .getDownloadURL();
          console.log(audiourl);
```

Having to send a request to Google's server for each download URL is not optimal. One option seems to be to store each of the download URLs in a firebase database and just call that when the app loads. Is there an efficient way to get the download URLs for each file without looping through the whole thing myself on the front end?

Also, would it be ok to just download from https://storage.cloud.google.com/firebaseappspot/path/flashcard1.mp3? The audio data does not contain private information. Do you have any other suggestions of how to store/get the audio URLs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an efficient way to get the download URLs for each file without looping through the whole thing myself on the front end?

Nothing more efficient than what you're doing now.  Getting a download URL requires the use of getDownloadURL as you are now, if you want them to have a token that can be revoked.  The main feature of that download URL is that they have an unguessable token (so they remain private to whomever has the URL), and the token can be revoked any time later.  The only way to generate this URL from the client is with getDownloadURL.

> Also, would it be ok to just download from https://storage.cloud.google.com/firebaseappspot/path/flashcard1.mp3?

That's entirely up to you and your security requirements.  If you want [objects to be public and accessible](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public), then so be it.